# Ionic resources ios gives "images too large for transformation" error

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

**Problem**

I succeeded in generating my Android resources using `ionic cordova resources android`, but `ionic cordova resources ios` gives an "images too large for transformation" error.

**This is what I tried without success**

- Updated Ionic CLI to latest version
- Removed and added ios platform
- Checked the image sizes: 1024 x 1024 for icon.png and 2732 x 2732 for splash.png
- Made sure the images have no alpha transparency

What could be the solution?

**(debug) info**

Output of `sudo ionic cordova resources ios --verbose --force`:

```
[DEBUG] CLI flags: { interactive: true, confirm: false }
[DEBUG] { cwd: '/Users/the/root/of/my/project', local: false, binPath: 
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic', libPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/dist/index.js' }
[DEBUG] Daemon found (pid: 1757)
[DEBUG] resourceJsonStructure=3
[DEBUG] platformEngines=android
✔ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!

? Platform ios not detected. Would you like to install it? Yes
> cordova platform add ios --save
✖ Running command - failed!
[WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.
> cordova platform save
✔ Running command - done!
[DEBUG] platformEngines=[object Object]
[DEBUG] buildPlatforms=android
[DEBUG] getProjectPlatforms completed - length=1
[DEBUG] imgResources=0
[DEBUG] createImgDestinationDirectories completed - length=0
[DEBUG] getSourceImages completed - 2
✔ Filtering out image resources that do not need regeneration - done!
[DEBUG] uploadSourceImages completed - responses=[
       {},
       {}
    ]
✔ Uploading source images to prepare for transformations - done!
[OK] No need to regenerate images--images too large for transformation.
```

Note: it keeps complaining about the missing ios platform, while in fact it has been installed.

This is my Ionic information:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.4.0

System:

    ios-deploy : 1.9.0 
    ios-sim    : 5.0.13 
    Node       : v6.9.4
    npm        : 3.10.10 
    OS         : macOS Sierra
    Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by errors in the platform. A clean install of my project solved the problems.

Comment: how? could explain by giving more details or the commands used please?

Comment: @JanP please provide more details for this answer to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I forgot to rename my Illustrator file to "icon.ai". It showed the "images too large", but wasn't actually finding the image at all.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue I restarted mac and  Run this command  ionic Cordova resources ios --force also reboot the iPhone.